# How to correctly Min-Cut this network?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, optimization, network-flow

I'm trying to understand the right procedure for making cuts in max-flow min-cut problems.

In this network here https://i.stack.imgur.com/SornO.png with the dashed cut through the middle, when working out the capacity of this cut, you would not include the capacity 9 of the $v_3$ to $v_2$ edge, ***because*** it is going ***backwards*** towards S (though, if you would count the -4 if you were working out how much actual flow you were interrupting). This I understand.

But, I was told that if you were to make a cut say across edges $(v_3,t), (v_4,v_3), (v_2, v_4)$ you in fact don't count the capacity - and I ***think*** not even the flow, though please correct me if I'm wrong - of edge $(v_4, v_3)$ - why? How am I supposed to know which edges that I cut across to exclude from the calculations?

Is it because, if I were to cut all 3 of those edges, because ***all*** the edges supplying $v_4$ have been cut (namely $(v_2,v_4)$ ) then all edges leaving v4 are now defacto 'empty'?

If I'm right, then if I were to make a cut along $(s, v_2), (v_2,v_1)$ and $(v_1,v_3)$ then I wouldn't count $(v_2,v_1)$, since all edges supplying $v_2$ are already, so any capacity potentially leaving $v_2$ is already accounted for with another cut? Is this right - if not, what's the understanding behind this/procedure to follow?

Thanks very much, indeed!

Edit for future readers: it was the insightful comments supporting the accepted answer that brought it together for me, so check those out for the full explanation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A cut in a network isn't a line drawn through the picture. It is a partition of the vertices into two sets, $S$ and $T$, such that the source is in $S$ and the sink is in $T$. Then the capacity of a cut is the sum of the capacities of all the edges that go from a vertex in $S$ to a vertex in $T$.

Comment: Thanks, though that I do know, I'm just using the picture as an illustration of the ideas. What'd be the procedure on using capacities in your calcs of edges that come from those like the one in my question, i.e. Imagine drawing a line on the graph, splitting horizontally. Now, imagine simulating a cut by drawing another line, staring from above, going across the edges you choose. I was told that, cutting across the my edges above you would disclude (v4, v3)'s capacity from calculations, because, laying the edge left to right, your cut would cross it from underneath. But why does that matter?

Comment: You include the capacities of the edges that go from a vertex in $S$ to a vertex in $T$, and you exclude the edges that go from $S$ to $S$, or $T$ to $S$, or $T$ to $T$. So before you can make sense of which capacities to include and which to exclude, you have to know which vertices are in $S$ and which are in $T$; and once you know which vertices are in $S$ and which are in $T$, your problem disappears. "Simulating a cut by drawing a line" is bound to confuse you, until you remember that a cut is defined by $S$ and $T$, and only by $S$ and $T$.

Comment: To put it another way, a picture that doesn't tell you what $S$ is and what $T$ is does not illustrate any ideas; it just confuses them.

Comment: Ah, thank you! I understand it now - what I was told about 'if you lay an edge out horizontally left to right, and your drawn lines comes up through the edge from the bottom, so don't include it in the calculations' is correct. But the why behind it is because of what you said: the scenario I just described only happens when your ege is eminating from your T set. So as you explained, you ignore it. So thank you very much, you've really helped, I appreciate it.

Comment: Good. One way to show appreciation on this website is to "accept" the answer by clicking in the check mark next to it.

Comment: Ah OK, thank you. I'm pretty new here.